# Hadoop CDH4 Evaluation: Which Ubuntu would be preferred? Lucid or Precise

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, cdh4

I'm setting up a CDH4 in AWS for evaluation (we already have a CHD3 running on Ubuntu Lucid) and I'd like advice regarding any known gotchyas that I'd be likely to encounter if running it on Lucid vs. Precise.

Is it safer to set up the test cluster under Lucid ... more similar to our existing production system; or to set it up under Precise?  Which OS has the majority (plurality) of the development and testing community been running it under?

Answer (score 1):

CDH4 seems to have more bugs but again if you are planing to implement serialization services like Avro. Ubuntu 'precise' has pre-built packages. Where as for "lucid" you have to build your own.